# (.htaccess) 301 redirect with same url structure

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I use 301 redirect from non-WWW to WWW domain! Works fine, but links are different.

Example:

```
from - ggkj.com/posts/godzilla/43
to - www.ggkj.com/index.php?view=posts&author=godzilla&aid=43
```

my .htaccess 301 redirect code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example\.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

.htaccess code: http://pastebin.com/t3FA59uq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently what i use on my website with success:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{http_host} !^www.walterbax.ca [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.walterbax.ca/$1 [R=301,L]
```

EDIT: after looking into your question a little further I can tell you that your issue is improperly placed in the file. it must be hitting another rule that is rewriting it into URL variables.

I would start with a basic htaccess for the www. rule for testing and add to it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Well I don't know .htaccess - I use it because I need that 301! :D here is mine! http://pastebin.com/t3FA59uq

Comment: Put the code in the top, before all the code. Write RewriteEngine On only once

Comment: But, what do you want? Do you want to redirect from yourdomain to www.yourdomain or redirect ggkj.com/posts/godzilla/43
to www.ggkj.com/index.php?view=posts&author=godzilla&aid=43?? Or both? Your question isn´t clear!

Comment: I want from ggkj.com/posts/godzilla/43 to www.ggkj.com/posts/godzilla/43

Comment: My answer redirect all the trafic of your website without the www to a url with www. Example: ggkj.com/posts/godzilla/43 to www.ggkj.com/posts/godzilla/43. Clean your htacces file of other rewrite rules and save it at your root folder of your aplicattion. If it doesn´t work, there is an another problem with your rules in your htaccess.

Comment: Has your Apache enabled the mod_rewrite module? if it isn´t enabled, the rewrite rules don't work!

Comment: For test if this rule works, you can test with only the domain. Try to go to yourdomain.com without parameters and see if change to www.yourdomain.com

Comment: it changes successfully to WWW!

Comment: if it´s changes, there is a problem with your others rules. Revise it!! Your question is answered! And remember, put the code in the top of htaccess for be the first rule to apply

Comment: @AinārsSprosts Can you close the question? Your question is answered. If you have problems with your htaccess create a new question but that you asked is answered. Thanks!